# Jenkins Groovy scrip

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

I am struggling with groovy script in Jenkins - I want to automatically generate a job using JobDSL plugin.

Below variables are defined and I want to pass them to steps{shell{command(...)}} but I don't manage to do get the effect

```
def jobName = 'job-name'
def group = 'group'
def project = 'project-name'
def ext = 'jar'
.
.
.

job(jobName) {
.
.
.
    steps {
        shell{
            command('''downloadUrl=$(curl -s "http://{nexus-url}/service/rest/v1/search?repository=maven-public&group=$group&name=$project&maven.extension=$ext"...''')
        }
    }
}
```

The result which I get in build step is

```
downloadUrl=$(curl -s "http://nexus.lab.pl/service/rest/v1/search?repository=maven-public&group=$group&name=$project&maven.extension=$ext..."
```

I have tried many ways to push the variables but I can't find the proper way.
Could someone teach me how to get demanded effect ?

Tried many ways to get proper result in bash style methods

Answer (score 0):

Triple-single-quoted strings are not interpolated so you cannot use `$variable` syntax inside them. See [String summary table](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_summary_table).

You can use double-quoted strings for this but you'll also need to escape double quotes and unrelated dollar signs inside the string itself:

```
command("downloadUrl=\$(curl -s \"http://{nexus-url}/service/rest/v1/search?repository=maven-public&group=$group&name=$project&maven.extension=$ext\"...")
```

Alternatively, you can also use [Dollar slashy string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_dollar_slashy_string) to avoid escaping:

```
command($/downloadUrl=$(curl -s "http://{nexus-url}/service/rest/v1/search?repository=maven-public&group=$group&name=$project&maven.extension=$ext"... /$)
```

Answer (score 0):

For maven You can use [maven plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/) with pom, settings and other maven staff

Also jenkins provide [httpRequest plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/http_request/)

And finaly You can use [groovy url](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html) ([example](https://gist.github.com/mzagar/59f3025240efa877d29e))